# ¿Cómo puedo extraer la primera palabra de una variable en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo puedo extraer la primera palabra de una variable, por ejemplo, `var nombre = "Pepito Grillo"` a `var nombreextraido = "Pepito"`?

```js
function cortar() {
 var nombresincortar = document.getElementById("nombre").value
 var nombrecortado = "¿?"
 document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "<p>" + nombrecortado +"</p>"
}
```

```html
<input id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."> <button onclick="cortar()">Cortar</button>
<div id="final"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Como determinas que es la primer palabra? ¿El separador es siempre un espacio?

Comment: Por favor prueba `console.log(nombre.split(" ")[0])` Esto crea un array donde tu cadena de texto es separada en palabras rompiéndola por los espacios en blanco `" "`

Comment: @BetaM ya está editado

Answer (score 2):

Yo comprendo que siempre haces el `split` con separación ( o sea " " ) , y a partir de ahí, yo haría.

```js
function cortar() {
  var nombresincortar = document.getElementById("nombre").value
  var nombrecortado = nombresincortar.split(" ");
  var primernombre = nombrecortado[0];
  document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "<p>" + primernombre + "</p>"
}
```

```html
<input id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..."> <button onclick="cortar()">Cortar</button>
<div id="final"></div>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Usa la función split para separar por espacios y selecciona la primera posición del array:

```
var nombre = "Pepito Grillo";
var nombreextraido = nombre.split(' ')[0];
```